# Concatenation is not working in select query

Tags: mysql, concatenation

We are fetching list of ordered products from database including join with order table.

We want to list all orders with how many quantity of products order in each order on the basis of passed product ids. We also want to display customer name which was placed the order.  So, as per our knowledge we have created an query to get items as:

```
SELECT 
  `main_table`.*, 
  `order`.*, 
  SUM(main_table.qty_ordered - main_table.qty_canceled) AS `custom_qty`, 
  SUM(main_table.row_total) AS `custom_row_total`, 
  SUM(main_table.tax_amount) AS `tax_amount`, 
  SUM(main_table.hidden_tax_amount) AS `hidden_tax_amount`, 
  SUM(main_table.discount_amount) AS `discount_amount`, 
  CONCAT(order.customer_firstname, ' ' ,order.customer_middlename, ' ', order.customer_lastname) AS full_name 
FROM `sales_flat_order_item` AS `main_table` 
INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `order` ON main_table.order_id=order.entity_id 
WHERE (((((main_table.product_id = '902') OR (main_table.product_id = '903') OR (main_table.product_id = '904'))))) AND (main_table.store_id = '1') AND (CONCAT(order.customer_firstname, order.customer_middlename, order.customer_lastname) like '%rag%') 
GROUP BY `main_table`.`sku`
```

All the aggregate functions used in above query working fine except concat(). Every time we will get the value of full_name column as NULL even we have name the corresponding concatenated columns.

Please any one helps me to figure out why this is not working. Are we doing something wrong in the above query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As CONCAT() returns NULL if any argument is NULL I'm guessing maybe one of the three arguments is NULL?

Answer (score 1):

As `CONCAT()` returns `NULL` if any argument is `NULL` I'm guessing maybe one of the three arguments is `NULL`?

Try using the `CONCAT_WS()` function instead (as you use separators anyway) which skips null values.

```
CONCAT_WS(' ', order.customer_firstname, order.customer_middlename, order.customer_lastname) AS full_name
```

See [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) for more information.

On a side note: you might want to look into how you can use table aliases to shorten the query text and make it more readable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, we have checked the value of all three columns and found that one of these column has NULL value. So as per your suggestion, we have used concat_ws() and its giving the value but not right value. Suppose my firstname = 'raghu', middlename = NULL and lastname = 'Kumar' then its giving us concatenated value as 'raghu raghuKumar' instead of 'raghu kumar'.

Comment: @user2393886 That sounds really odd, are you sure about the values and that you didn't repeat firstname in the concat_ws by accident? My test shows this as working: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad41d4/1

Comment: Thanks, it is working fine now. We have made a little silly mistake in syntax as result it was giving us improper value.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure EVERY column has an value? (Middlename?)

The MYSQL manual says:

SELECT CONCAT('My', NULL, 'QL') 
        -> NULL

Comment: Thanks for your reply, we have checked the value of all three columns and found that one of these column has NULL value. So as per your suggestion, we have used concat_ws() and its giving the value but not right value. Suppose my firstname = 'raghu', middlename = NULL and lastname = 'Kumar' then its giving us concatenated value as 'raghu raghuKumar' instead of 'raghu kumar'.